# Two similar for-loops give different results

Tags: c, for-loop

just playing around with for loops, and wanted to see what the results are.

I'm assuming both produce the same results, but I'm wrong.

```
        int sum ,sum2 , i , j;

        for(  sum = 0,  i = 1 ; i <= 5 ; sum+=i , i++ )
            printf("%d\t",sum);

        printf("\n");

        for(  sum2 = 0, j = 1 ; j <= 5 ; j++ ) {
            sum2 +=j;
            printf("%d\t",sum2); }
```

```
 0  1   3   6   10
 1  3   6   10  15
```

Answer (score 4):

In the first loop `sum` is incremented at the end of the iteration, so after the call to `printf`, while in the second loop `sum2` is incremented before the call to `printf`.

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the execution pointer carefully, in the first loop `sum += i` occurs *before* `i` is incremented.

In the second loop, `sum2 += j` occurs *after* `j` has been incremented.